# How to center part of a navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have my navbar as follow:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" id="header">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            Welcome
        </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>@*<a href="LogOff"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>Log out</a>*@
                <form action="LogOff">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="logoff" value="LogOff" />
                </form>
            </li>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I want the Welcome bar to be centered in my page.  I tried with css:

```
.navbar-header
{
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

But my Welcome is still left aligned.  Any idea of how to center the Welcome?

Added:

```
#header
{
    background-color:#293939 ;
    color: White;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:17px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: please provide respective css

Comment: Add `float: none;` to `.navbar-header`.

Comment: You may have a overriding css class. Please provide the complete css.

Comment: See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g1eybpv2/2/), it is centered.

Comment: I have added more css.  But I tried adding float: none , it still does not work.  On the fiddle it works, but not in my app.

Comment: it work in my fiddle to here it is **https://jsfiddle.net/m6984whw/11/**

Comment: Yes it works in a fiddle. But not in my app. I am using a layout.

Comment: May I suggest you temporary give "header", "container-fluid" and "navbar-header" one background color each, then you will _see_ their size and much more easily detect which elements you need to change.

Comment: Good idea @LGSon!  Actually now I can see that the "navbar-header" is positioned to the left. So I fixed its width. And now it works!  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it some max-width , and an auto margin on left and right sides.

i.e.

```
.navbar-header
{
   max-width: 250px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```